# Ending position out of bound exception

Tags: apex, trigger, exception, loop

I have below trigger that is getting below. I want just the letter after '-' to be in uppercase.

> Compile Error:  execution of BeforeUpdate caused by:
>   System.StringException: Ending position out of bounds: 1:
>   At Line :
>
> { guess = guess.substring(0,guess.indexOf('-'))+
>   guess.substring(guess.indexOf('-'),1).toUppercase() +
>   guess.substring(guess.indexOf('-')+1,guess.length()-1);

Can someone please help.

Trigger:

```
 trigger ACCOUNT_AFTER_INSUPD_NAME on Account (before insert , before update) {

    /*List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();
    acc = [SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,Middle_vod__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN Trigger.oldMap.keySet() LIMIT 1];*/
    for(Account a: trigger.new)
    {

            if(a.Ispersonaccount==true)
            {
                    String f = a.FirstName;
                    List<String> FName= f.split(' ');
                    for(Integer i=0;i<FName.size();i++)
                    {
                            FName[i] = (FName[i].substring(0,1)).toUppercase() +(FName[i].substring(1,FName[i].length()).toLowercase());
                            if(i>0)
                            {
                                    a.FirstName=a.FirstName+' '+FName[i];
                            }
                            else a.FirstName=FName[i];
                    }

                    String m = a.Middle_vod__c;
                    if(m != null){
                            List<String> MName= m.split(' ');
                            for(Integer i=0;i<MName.size();i++)
                            {
                                    MName[i] = (MName[i].substring(0,1)).toUppercase() +(MName[i].substring(1,MName[i].length()).toLowercase());
                                    if(i>0)
                                    {
                                            a.Middle_vod__c=a.Middle_vod__c+' '+MName[i];
                                    }
                                    else a.Middle_vod__c=MName[i];

                            }
                    }

                    String l = a.LastName;
                    List<String> LName= l.split(' ');
                    for(Integer i=0;i<LName.size();i++)
                    {
                            LName[i] = (LName[i].substring(0,1)).toUppercase() +(LName[i].substring(1,LName[i].length()).toLowercase());
                            if(i>0)
                            {
                                    a.LastName=a.LastName+' '+LName[i];
                            }
                            else a.LastName=LName[i];

                    }

                    // For Mc'
                    String N = a.FirstName+' '+a.Middle_vod__c+' '+a.lastname;
                    String McName =a.Name;
                    List<String> FindName= N.split(' Mc');
                    for(Integer i=0;i<FindName.size();i++)
                    {  
                            FindName[i] = (FindName[i].substring(0,1)).toUppercase() +(FindName[i].substring(1,FindName[i].length()));
                            system.debug(FindName[i]+'1111');
                            if(i>0)
                            {
                                    McName=McName+' Mc'+FindName[i];
                                    system.debug(McName+'Line63');   
                            }
                            else McName=FindName[i];
                    }
                    a.Name=McName;

                    system.debug(a.Name+'Line63'); 
                    //
                    //update a;
            }

            // For Business Accounts
            else { 
                    String business = a.Name;
                    List<String> BName= business.split(' ');
                    for(Integer i=0;i<BName.size();i++)
                    {
                            BName[i] = (BName[i].substring(0,1)).toUppercase() +(BName[i].substring(1,BName[i].length()).toLowercase());
                            if(i>0)
                            {
                                    a.Name=a.Name+' '+BName[i];
                            }
                            else a.Name=BName[i];
                    } 
            } 

            system.debug(a.name);   

            // Special Characters for any Account    
            if(a.name.contains('-')) 
            {
                    String Acc=a.name;
                    system.debug(a.name); 
                    for (integer index = 0;index<1;index++)
                    {       
                            system.debug(Acc.substring(Acc.indexOf('-')+1,Acc.indexOf('-')+2).toUppercase()+'@@'); 
                            system.debug(Acc.substring(Acc.indexOf('-')+1,Acc.length())+'@@'); 
                            system.debug(Acc.substring(0,Acc.indexOf('-'))+'@@'); 
                            String X=Acc.substring(Acc.indexOf('-')+1,Acc.indexOf('-')+2).toUppercase();
                            Acc = Acc.substring(0,Acc.indexOf('-'))+ 
                                    Acc.substring(Acc.indexOf('-'),Acc.indexOf('-')+2).toUppercase() + 
                                    Acc.substring(Acc.indexOf('-')+2,Acc.length());
                            system.debug(Acc+'@315691'); 

                    }
                    a.Name=Acc;
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add what's in the guess String? Your line of code contains 3 substrings, each of which can cause the errormessage.

Comment: Yes it is there. String guess=a.name;

Comment: I'm interested in the actual contents of the string at the time the error occurs. So in this particular example (where the error occurs), what do you see if you put system.debug(a.name); ?

Comment: It is printing "Lean Xyz-yyKumar LeanNeogy Lean" but it should be "Saikat Mclean Xyz-Yy Kumar Mclean Neogy Mclean"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have been confused by the exact syntax of .substring:

> substring(Integer, Integer)
>
> Returns a new String that begins with the character at the specified
>   zero-based startIndex and extends to the character at endIndex - 1.

So the second substring is taking *from* first occurrence of - *until* index 1. That's not possible as 1 is smaller then the index of the first occurrence of -.

So you'd have to change your code to the following:

```
guess = guess.substring(0,guess.indexOf('-'))+ 
    guess.substring(guess.indexOf('-'),guess.indexOf('-')+2).toUppercase() + 
    guess.substring(guess.indexOf('-')+2,guess.length());
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not giving my desired output.

Comment: I am getting " Saikat Mclean Xyz-yy Neogy Mclean " without anyfailure. I expect "Saikat Mclean Xyz-Yy Neogy Mclean"

Comment: Strange! I input this string `Lean Xyz-yyKumar LeanNeogy Lean` and the output is `Lean Xyz-YyKumar LeanNeogy Lean` using the exact same code above. Which is per your requirement. the letter right after '-' is capitalized.

Comment: Even I am getting this in debug log now. But update not happening.        |DEBUG|Saikat McLean Xyz-Yyyyyy Kumar McLean Neogy McLean@315691

Comment: Can you please let me know my error in code?

Comment: Strange I did the same in a different org and it works! Strange!! Is there any settings that I need to enable?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be a setting that does such a thing. Maybe there's another trigger or a workflow resetting the value

Comment: If that is the case where can I see it? Only in debug log right? No triggers I can find here.

Comment: Yes it should all be in the debug log. Is there anything below the last system.debug?

Comment: Please find the debug log here. It shows desired result but not in updates. In latter section where workflow evaluations are show desired output not coming                                                                             13:15:48.158 (158780275)|USER_DEBUG|[127]|DEBUG|Saikat Xy-Z McLean Pgr Xyz McLean Abc McLe'A-n@315691
13:15:48.158 (158787456)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[127]|System.debug(ANY)
13:15:48.158 (158799361)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[5]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
13:15:48.158 (158821770)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[5]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()

Comment: I can't really check that anymore because I can't see line [127] (it must have been added later) and also I can't see your full debug log..